# How can I change character class to numeric class?

Tags: r, class

I have a variable like this:

| VALOR |
| --- |
| 3.554,34 |
| 56,34 |

But its class is "character" and when I code this:

```
gastosbolsonaro <- gastosbolsonaro %>% mutate(VALOR = as.numeric(VALOR))
```

Happening this:

```
Problem while computing `VALOR = as.numeric(as.character(VALOR))`.
i NAs introduced by coercion
```

And all value change to NA's.

I want to change value money to numeric class

Comment: It's because you have comma "," in your `VALOR` column.

Comment: @benson23 just to highlight, that's a regional notation issue.  Some regions use "," as the decimal separator and "." as the every-three-orders grouping mark, the opposite of what you may be used to.  See Jilber Urbina's answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `parse_number` from readr package

```
library(readr)
x <- c("3.554,34", "56,34")
parse_number(x, locale = locale(decimal_mark = ",", grouping_mark = "."))
[1] 3554.34   56.34
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `.`, change `,` to `.` and then convert using `as.numeric`.

```
x <- c("3.554,34", "56,34")
. <- gsub(".", "", x, fixed = TRUE)
. <- sub(",", ".", .)
as.numeric(.)
#[1] 3554.34   56.34
```

Or in one line:

```
as.numeric(sub(",", ".", gsub("\\.", "", x)))
#[1] 3554.34   56.34
```

Another *base* option using `scan`.

```
scan(text=gsub("\\.", "", x), dec=",")
#scan(text=gsub("\\.", "", x), dec=",", quiet = TRUE) #Quiet Alternative 
#[1] 3554.34   56.34
```